# WAL Sender and WAL receiver both running on both sides

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres master-slave lab setup that worked properly.  However, today it stopped working and I noticed that both sides (the master and slave sides) have both WAL Sender and WAL receiver services running.  How come those two services are running on the same machine and how did this same problem occurred on both sides?

Any idea what might have caused it?
Any idea how can I fix this setup?

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Look at the log files, they should tell you. What do you get for `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` on both machines?

Comment: pg_is_in_recovery is true on both sides.  I did not see anything in the log that can explain this.

Comment: Well, figure out to which machine and which port the walreceivers are connected to. That might give you a clue. Besides, there *must* be an entry in the log of the machine that sudenly changed to be a slave, because that only can happen after a restart. Perhaps the "new slave" is actually recovering from a crash?

Comment: This is the output of ps -ef from both servers                                        postgres 18366  1508  0 15:36 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process postgres 172.19.255.101(36249) streaming 1/A8000098
postgres 18377  1508  0 15:36 ?        00:00:01 postgres: wal receiver process
AND FROM THE OTHER SERVER - 
postgres  2610  2602  0 15:36 ?        00:00:01 postgres: wal receiver process
postgres  2686  2602  0 15:36 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process postgres 172.19.255.102(51382) streaming 1/A8000098

Comment: Sounds like you created a recovery.conf on the master

Comment: @user1409708, you should focus on a) finding out to which machines the WAL receivers are connected (UNIX `lsof` and similar tools will help) and b) finding the last restart of the "master" in the logs and reading what happened. If they really are conected to each other, remove `recovery.conf` on the "master" and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt to answer this using a crystal ball, since there is not enough information:

If the two servers are really connected to and reading WAL from each other, there must be

- a file `recovery.conf` in the “master” server's data directory that tells it to connect to the “slave”.
- a restart of the master somewhere in the past. Look for it in the log files.

In that case, the solution is to stop the master, remove or rename `recovery.conf` and start it again.

If your problem is a different one, use `lsof` to see to which machines the WAL receivers are connected and proceed from there.